# JTable inside a JPanel sets its own border and fix size

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, layout-manager

Im trying to learn Java and using the GUI as an upgrade to the "booring" C\C++ 
I had two panels, one of them with an input form, and one of them with a table which suppose to show the things I load from the input form.

But no idea why, the table expands and has a border line, moreover, it has a fixed size and whenever I expand the window, the table stays the same.

The "mainFrame" (the file that calls the c'tor) just initiate the table and add it to the layout so im sure its not happening there...

I've added the JTable class code and a picture showing whats happening

The link if it shows too small : http://oi62.tinypic.com/ok4hs5.jpg

[image]

And the code :

```
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
public class TableOutput extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable jt;

    public TableOutput() {
        String[] columns = {"Product ID" , "Date" , "Name" , "Address" , "Status"};
        String[][] data = {};
        jt = new JTable(data,columns);
        jt.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jt, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        add(jsp);
    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 2) Use a logical & consistent code formatting style!  The code indentation is intended to help people follow the program flow.

Comment: *"The "mainFrame" (the file that calls the c'tor) just initiate the table and add it to the layout so im sure its not happening there..."*  Don't be so sure, post an MCVE.  Some (layout constraints of some) layouts will stretch components width, height or both to fill the available space.  Others will leave components at their preferred size.

Comment: BTW - the default layout of a `JPanel` is `FlowLayout` which will leave components as their preferred size (no stretch).  Also, better to use an instance of a panel than extend it, since the code is not really changing the behavior of a panel, just adding components to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But no idea why, the table expands and has a border line, moreover, it has a fixed size

- *size* - Do `System.out.println(table.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize())`. This is the method the scroll pane calls to get the preferred size for the table view. You will see that the default it 450x400. You can change it by overriding         `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` on the table.

  ```
  JTable table = new JTable() {
      public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
          return new Dimension(300, 300);
      }
  };
  ```
- *border* - that's not the table border. It's actually the scroll pane border.

> whenever I expand the window, the table stays the same.

`JPanel` has a default `FlowLayout`, which will always respect the preferred size of the contained component. If you want the table/scrollpane to stretch with the panel, use a layout manager like `BorderLayout` which will disregard the preferred size and stretch to fit. Keep in mind that if the panel is contained by a container with the FlowLayout, you will still get your current result. If the panel is just being added the frame with its default `BorderLayout`, then you should be fine. See more at [How to use Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

**Note:** You may find out though that if you want to set the layout the BorderLayout, the preferred size of the scroll pane will have no effect. This will leave you will the same result - the table will big with empty rows and the border.

Comment: Thank you very much, the explanation was brief and it solved the problem.